# filter properties with Objectify 4

Tags: google-app-engine, frameworks, objectify

I'm trying to filter with Objectify in GAE:

```
List<users> ul =  ofy.load().type(Usuario.class).filter("name", "gildus").list();
```

In the User's class use anotation @Index:

```
@Entity
public class Users {

@Id
private Long id;

@Index
private String name;

...
```

The filter result is empty, although there is value "gildus". When I use the ID field if it shows results (....filter("id", "1").list() ).

What more could I do to make it work ?

Comment: Please provide more details about the problem. What doesn't work?

Comment: I deleted all the records and then reinstalled and everything works normally. The problem or mistake was that there were records indexed and unindexed, that is why the filter did not work correctly.

regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I use the ID field if it shows results `(....filter("id", "1").list() )`.

Don't use filter for `id`. Use the following instead:

```
Usuario user = ofy.load().type(Usuario.class).id(1).get();
```

Comment: When are not index? Its necesary to make a filter.

Comment: When the field is annotated with @Id, it is always indexed.
And filtering only works on indexed fields too.